# how to pass a decimal number to a rest web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I am wanting to pass a decimal number (1.23) to my WCF-REST web service.

I keep getting a 'resource cannot be found' error.  I expect that I'm encountering some security feature of IIS where urls that contain a dot are a resource.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to pass a decimal number to my webservice?

Sample url... http://localhost/restdataservice.svc/echo/2.2

Operation Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "echo/{number}")]
string Echo(string number);
```

And implementation

```
public string Foo(string number)
{
  return number;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you user your browser to browse to the URL without the `number` parameter, just to `/echo`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at IIS log to see the problem. One thing that can cause such problem is [UrlScan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc242650). It has UrlScan.ini config file, where you can find *AllowDotInPath* parameter. If it is set to *0*, requests such as above would be rejected. Just change it to *1* (but don't forget to ensure, that you don't allow directory traversals by rejecting urls with ..).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider sending that number to your resource in a request representation using a POST request.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine out of the box, I cannot reproduce this problem with a similar basic setup - are you sure the default route for your `echo` method is set correctly?

Comment: I believe this is a problem with Cassini Web Server that is included with Visual Studio.

Comment: @amit_g: I'm using Cassini as well to test, works fine for me

Comment: I can reproduce this using VS2010 when using Cassini. Same project when browsed through IIS works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem calling a method on a WCF OData Server.

The problem was that a decimal parameter requires an 'm' at the end.

```
http://localhost/restdataservice.svc/echo/2.2m
```